# в андроид студио <style> подчёркивается красным

Tags: java, android-studio

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEnter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="496dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPink"
    android:hint="Введите данные"
    android:textSize="18sp"


    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</EditText>
<style name="MyBox">
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
</style>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
    android:layout_width="209dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="218dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/btnEnter"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А кто разрешил писать стиль в файл разметки?

Comment: а куда нужно писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы все работало правильно и на вас никто не ругался, вам нужно создать отдельные стили для вашего вью элемента. Для этого перейдите в файл `res/values/styles.xml`
если его нету, то создайте. Дальше у него будет такая структура:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="GreenText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

В коде выше вы сделаете цвет текста зеленым. Подключаем его к вьюшке:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/GreenText"
    ... />
```

и дальше происходит магия)) Ваш стиль нужно вынести так:

```
<style name="MyBox">
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
</style>
```

и подключить его к вьюхе:

```
style="@style/MyBox"
```

В разметке активности нельзя создавать и прописывать стили для вью элементов активности, для этого есть отдельные файлы. Так же вы можете создать свою тему где все будет прописано. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) есть документация по вашему вопросу.